# How to copy and paste a color in Pixelmator?

Tags: color, pixelmator

Is there an easy way to copy and paste a color? I keep having to remember the RGB values and it's kind of a pain...

For example, if I make a circle shape and set it's color to 123 44 5, can I somehow copy that value and paste it onto a triangle shape I make in a different file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pixelmator uses the native Mac color picker. As a result, you can actually save colors using the picker itself.

1. Select your color.
2. Bring up the color picker (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>)
3. Drag the Color from the Large Color Selection to the Palette at the bottom
4. Select your second object.
5. Bring up the color picker again and select your color from the picker.

For even more convenience, you can also use the eye dropper from the color picker to pick colors from anywhere on your screen.

I've recorded a quick GIF screencast for you.

[image: Quick Screencast]

Comment: I really do like Pixelmator, but the lack of details in some basic things--such as color management and color picking--does make for a frustrating experience at times.

Comment: What gif editor did you use and capture software?

Comment: Glad I could help. Pixelmator is slowly maturing and as a small team of devs building the app, they are stellar! I used LICEcap. It directly screencasts into GIF and works on Mac and Windows.